# Python MP3Play with Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create an MP3Player with python (not using any fancy GUIs, just basic command-line). You are able to input commands like "playlist" which prints all songs or "play [num]" which plays the specified song in your playlist. I can do this all in the one thread, but what I want is to create another thread so you can do more commands like "add song" or "delete song" while the actual music is playing (instead of the command line waiting for the music to finish). Here is what I have with one thread:

```
import mp3play, time
clip = mp3play.load(song)
clip.play()
time.sleep(clip.seconds()) #Waits the duration of the song
clip.stop()
#Command line asks for input after this
```

This works all fine and dandy, but when I try to implement threading into this, like this:

```
import mp3play, time

def play(songname):
    clip = mp3play.load(song)
    clip.play()
    time.sleep(clip.seconds()) #Waits the duration of the song
    clip.stop()

#Get user input here
#Check if user inputted command
#User inputed "play"
thread.start_new_thread(play,("some_random_song.mp3",))
```

It glitches out. It all seems fine until you close the application half way through the song and the music still keeps running. To stop the music, I have to open Task Manager and end the task. So I thought about having a "stop" command as well, which wouldn't close the thread, but it would use

```
clip.stop()
```

I don't know what happens if you try to stop() a clip that isn't running, so I implemented a prevention system (boolean running that checks if it is or not). But now nothing works, so far here is my code:

```
def play(filename):
    global clip
    clip.play()
    time.sleep(clip.seconds())
    clip.stop()

playing = False
clip = ""

#Get user input
#blah blah blah command stuff
#User inputted "play"
thread.start_new_thread(play,("some_random_song.mp3",))
playing = True
#Goes back to command line
#User inputted 'stop' this time
if playing:
    clip.stop()
    playing = False
```

But when I try to run this, it gets to clip.play() in the thread but doesnt start it. Im not sure how I can get around this, and if it's possible to do this without threading. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to play MP3's using a different process, using `multiprocessing.Process`.

Write a function that takes the path to an MP3 file, and start that as a `Process`.

For technical reasons, the dominant python implementation (from python.org) restricts threading so that only one thread at a time can be executing python bytecode. This will probably never be glitch free.

Comment: When I type "play" it starts to play the music, but it does not show the pointer ">" asking for the next command (i.e. the thread is tied up `sleep`ing for the mp3play `clip`). Am I doing something wrong?